# Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set on Unload Me

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

My problem is that I try to use the "Unload Me" option, but I constantly receive an error that says "Object variable or With block variable not set". There's no error when I'm going to remove the `Unload Me`.

```
If i = 0 Then
   MsgBox "The learner has not yet been graded for this quarter!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
   Unload InputGrds
End If
```

The flow that I'm thinking is that if the `IF statement` above is equals `0` then there will be a `MsgBox` that will say that the learner is not yet graded and the `UserForm` with a filename `InputGrds` will not appear.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    With InputGrds
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
        .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
    End With
    
    txtBox_LRN.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K11").Value)
    txtBox_lname.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K12").Value)
    txtBox_grd.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K16").Value)
    txtBox_qrt.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K17").Value)
    
    grd = txtBox_grd.Text
    
    Select Case grd
        Case "1"
           result = "Matthew"
           tb_epp.Enabled = False
        Case "2"
           result = "Mark"
           tb_epp.Enabled = False
   End Select
   
   txtBox_sec.Text = result
   
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("A1").Value = "I" Then
        Label1.Caption = "INPUT GRADES"
    ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("A1").Value = "U" Then
        Label1.Caption = "UPDATE GRADES"
        btnSave.Caption = "UPDATE"
        
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("G1-Q1")
        lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0
        
        For r = 10 To lastrow
        
            If ws.Cells(r, 3) = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K11").Value) Then
                tb_mtb.Text = ws.Cells(r, 9).Value
                tb_fil.Text = ws.Cells(r, 10).Value
                tb_eng.Text = ws.Cells(r, 11).Value
                tb_math.Text = ws.Cells(r, 12).Value
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Next r
        
        If i = 0 Then
            MsgBox "The learner has not yet been graded for this quarter!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
            Unload InputGrds
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's the `Module` code

```
Sub Input_Grds()
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("K16").Value) And Not IsEmpty(Range("K17").Value) Then
        InputGrds.Show 'When I clicked the Debug button, this is the highlighted line
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter a data in the SELECT DATA table.", vbRetryCancel + vbCritical, "SF10"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Set your error handling option to "break in class module" and see if anything is different when you click "Debug".

Comment: @TimWilliams it's the same. This `InputGrds.Show` line in the `Module` is the one that is highlighted.

Comment: OK then maybe check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259657/closing-a-form-on-initialize-throws-error  Also some good general-purpose reading on using userforms in VBA: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/

Comment: You shouldn't try and unload a form in its own `Initialize` event.

Comment: Thank you! I moved it on the `UserForm_Activate` and it seems to work now.